# Velocity JS and Dynamically Added DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs, velocity.js

I have two CodePens that describe my problem. I'm using Velocity to animate React-rendered elements on a page.

- [Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/rVMpYV)
- [Non-working CodePen](http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/qdapbZ)

The objective is to move these "articles" up and down the page based on rank. They are absolutely positioned, and I determine the position on the page based on `rank * height`.

The [working example](http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/rVMpYV) successfully displays all the elements, then after a `setTimeout` of 2 seconds it reverses the order.

The [non-working example](http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/qdapbZ) is supposed to do the exact same thing, but the only one it moves around the page is the final DOM object (`id=article-5`).

The only difference between the examples is that the [working example](http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/rVMpYV) has already-rendered DOM elements on the page, while the [non-working example](http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/qdapbZ) renders the HTML via JavaScript

```
var articlesContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('articles')[0];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  articlesContainer.innerHTML = articlesContainer.innerHTML + '<div id=article-' + i + '></div>';
}
```

Not really sure why that dynamic adding of the HTML elements would break this. It's worth noting that the first 4 elements that fail to animate have the class `velocity-animating`, which means that Velocity at least tried to animate the object, but seemingly failed along the way somewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `articlesContainer.innerHTML = newHTML`, you're unmounting all nodes in articlesContainer and mounting new ones. Velocity/React thus operate on detached nodes, except for the last article node which is the only one not unmounted. Use `document.createElement` and `node.appendChild` instead:

```js
var articlesContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('articles')[0];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  articlesContainer.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Working codepen http://codepen.io/migreva/pen/pJEOjq. Still getting used to Javascript without jQuery, it's been a painful process